# Clarification on FTP - ASCII vs. binary transfer mode after having corrupted files

Tags: linux, ftp, file-transfer, binary-files, ascii

Recently I wasted almost two hours before realizing that the file upload with Filezilla corrupted the files (e.g. adding unwanted spaces or special UTF-8 characters being corrupted) after downloading and uploading files of a project from one server to local (Linux Mint) and up to another. While 99.9% of the files were totally o.k. I had this issues in very few files causing the project not to run anymore.

Lets assume I only have FTP connection available. I also prefer SFTP or even better SSH but some clients' hosts simply do not offer it. Therefore I wonder which is a SAFE way to transfer data via FTP which is probably encoded in different ways and contains different characters.

I have noticed that in Filezilla there is a setting for ASCII vs. binary mode. I found the following explanation:

> There are two different modes for transferring files with FTP: "ASCII"
> and "binary" mode. The reason for the two different modes is that
> there are two distinct means of representing the end of a line in a
> text, or ASCII, file. On UNIX machines, the end of a line is
> represented by the character. This character is a control-J. Some UNIX
> commands, like od(1), represent this character with a "\n". For
> example, if you have a UNIX file named "foo":
>
> $ cat foo this is a test of the terminal that is shot from guns. $ od
> -c foo 00000000000 t h i s i s a t e s t o 00000000020 f \n t h e t e r m i n a l t 00000000040 h a t i s \n s h o t f r o m 00000000060 g u
> n s . \n 00000000067
>
> On PCs (and on Mainframe computers) the end of a line is represented
> by a  followed by a  character. This is a
> control-M followed by a control-J.
>
> In FTP, if you specify "ASCII" mode, if you are sending a file from a
> UNIX system to a PC, a control-M will be added before every control-J
> in the file. This will ensure that the ASCII/text file will be
> readable on the PC. Conversely, if you send a file in "ASCII" mode
> from a PC to a UNIX system, the combination control-M control-J will
> get changed into a control-J. File size will decrease by one byte per
> line when sending from a PC to a UNIX system; file size will increase
> by one byte per line when sending from a UNIX system to a PC. When
> sending between two PCs -- or two UNIX systems -- files send in
> "ASCII" mode will be unchanged.
>
> Files sent in "binary" mode are sent from one system to another with
> no modification. The file size will always be unchanged on a binary
> transfer.
>
> "ASCII" mode is appropriate when using FTP to send a single text file
> between two PCs. "binary" mode is appropriate when sending anything
> else: TAR files, compressed files, gzip'd files, CA-Alexandria
> binaries, etc. If a binary file is sent between a PC and a UNIX system
> in "ASCII" mode, the contents of the binary file will be modified such
> that it will no longer be readable; the file will have to be re-sent
> from the originating system in binary mode. Typically, this is the
> source of the problem when a customer sends us TAR or compressed files
> that are not readable on our machines.
>
> Additionally, everyone should remember that since our ftp site is an
> NT server, the default transfer mode is ascii. Our typical customer is
> a UNIX sys admin. They are used to sites that default to binary. When
> asking them to put files on our site, remind them that it defaults to
> ascii and that they will want to set binary mode.

(Source: https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/28212/ftp-ascii-vs-binary-mode-what-it-means.html)

According to this I assume that binary mode is always a safe way to go while ASCII mode may cause various problems? **Is my assumption correct** and are there any further settings to consider (e.g. regarding charset) in order to avoid issues like this with FTP GUI clients in the future?

Comment: I feel there's no reason for the ASCII mode to exist anymore. It's probably there for historical reasons. A file transfer protocol should not care about the contents of files nor alter it.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/4401/whats-the-point-of-ascii-mode-in-ftp

Comment: Any eol conversions will not affect UTF encoding ...

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications so far!